Working with Visual Code and WSL Ubuntu on multi Linux User
I have WSL Ubuntu 22 installed on my Windows machine and going to use it as my development environment.
I have "oscar" user and "john" as my second user
So inside of my "Home" dir, it is showing like this:
/home/
--john
--oscar
All my files are on "john" home dir.
Now, I stuck with how to open my files from Visual Code on my windows?
I use Visual Code WSL extension v0.66.3 but the thing is when I try to Open Folder, my "john" home dir does not detected.

Additional information,
when I go to my WSL Terminal try "su john" and do "code ." --> it gives me "Command 'code' not found, did you mean:........"
How to make my "john" home dir detected?

To confirm, do you have the users oscar and john in windows as well?

Looking from Explorer - Linux - Ubuntu 22 - Home --> Yes, i have oscar and john.
But, my windows machine does not have user neither oscar or john.

After a few hours struggle, I know what is the cause.
I installed 2 Linux, 1 is Ubuntu and 2 is Ubuntu-22
Seems by default VS Code only detecting my 1st Ubuntu.
After I unregister my 1st Ubuntu using wslconfig, everything goes well.
